# Get IP of application in local cluster

Tags: azure-service-fabric-mesh

I followed Microsoft's tutorial and learned that I can run this command

```
az mesh gateway show --resource-group Mesh --name todolistappGateway
```

to find the IP address I need to call to access my application in the cloud. How do I find the IP I should call to access the instance of my application running in my local service fabric mesh cluster? If I start debugging in Visual Studio, it opens a browser which contains the IP I need but what is the correct way to find this?

Comment: Never mind my answer, I didn't notice you wanted to run it locally. I haven't used locally for a while, so don't remember how to get the IP. Have you tried SF Explorer?

Comment: You can try this thread: https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-mesh-preview/issues/328

Comment: @DiegoMendes I have tried the explorer but haven't got anything yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`docker inspect` on the application container (not the reverse proxy) will give you the same IP address as what's being launched by Visual Studio but I'm still not certain that's the best way.